# Make helm window the only window

Tags: window, helm

Sometimes when I am using helm, I want to make the helm completion buffer as big as possible. I know that `helm-enlarge-window` will make the window grow by 1 line, but this is awkward and still doesn't quite achieve the desired result.  I also know that setting `(setq helm-full-frame t)` will make helm open full-frame by default, but I don't want all helm buffer full frame all the time.

What I really want is to bind a key that will instantly expand the helm completion buffer to full-frame.  I have tried this (where `*helm XYZ*` is the name of the current helm buffer):

```
 (with-current-buffer "*helm XYZ*" (delete-other-windows))
```

but I get the error "Can't expand minibuffer to full frame."  Any other suggestions for how I can toggle the helm buffer to be full frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you get is because point is in the minibuffer waiting for completion when you call `with-current-buffer`. Fortunately, `helm` provides `helm-window` to select the completion window. The following function leverages this to achieve what you want.

```
 (defun my-make-helm-full-frame ()
   (interactive)
   (with-selected-window (helm-window)
     (delete-other-windows)))
```

Bind it to a key in `helm-map` like this

```
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<f9>") 'my-make-helm-full-frame)
```

so that pressing `F9` when helm is active maximized the window. Pressing `C-g` quits `helm` and restores your original window. If you use `winner-mode` you can call `winner-undo` bound to `C-c left` to restore the completion window to its original size.

Comment: I needed to add `(require 'helm)` to my init file first to get this working. I'm also finding the bit with `winner-mode` to behave a bit strange. Often it makes the Helm window disappear completely.